# PowerShell: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens' when calling Connect-ExchangeOnline

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to migrate away from DAP to GDAP + Exchange Online PowerShell v3 to comply with Microsoft's migration deadline of March 31st, 2023. We're following [Microsoft's own documentation and code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/partnercenter/exchange-online-gdap-app?view=partnercenterps-3.0). All calls to `Connect-ExchangeOnline` fail with `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens'`. We've opened a ticket with Microsoft but they've been unresponsive and their migration deadline is fast-approaching. Microsoft Support actually confirmed that our GDAP relationship was properly configured, and that our modules were correct. However, they've stopped responding and we're still stuck.

As per the [GDAP migration doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/partnercenter/exchange-online-gdap-app?view=partnercenterps-3.0), we've done the following:

- Created a new multi-tenant application in our partner tenant

  - Ensured `user_impersonation` permissions for the Partner Center API
- Installed ExchangeOnlineManagement 3.1.0
- Installed PartnerCenter 3.0.10
- Established a GDAP relationship between us and our customer tenant

  - Microsoft Support confirmed that the GDAP relationship was configured
  - GDAP relationship is using priviledged role admin
- The user account used to generate JWT tokens is a member of both AdminAgents and our newly-created GDAP security group

```
$AppId = "ABC-123"  // ID of the App Registration
$AppSecret = "XYZ-456"  // Secret for the App Registration
$CustomerTenantId = "XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX"  // Tenant ID of client environment
$AppCredential = (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($AppId, (ConvertTo-SecureString $AppSecret -AsPlainText -Force)))
$token = New-PartnerAccessToken -ApplicationId $AppId -Scopes 'https://outlook.office365.com/.default' -ServicePrincipal -Credential $AppCredential -Tenant $CustomerTenantId -UseAuthorizationCode
Connect-ExchangeOnline -DelegatedOrganization $CustomerTenantId -AccessToken $token.AccessToken
```

```bash
$ OperationStopped: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=6.22.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXX'.
```

Note: this issue happens when we use the non-interactive refresh token flow as well. This interactive auth token flow shown above is just for demonstration purposes. Any call to `Connect-ExchangeOnline` yields the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were finally able to resolve this issue both locally and in our Azure FunctionApps. We were using PowerShell v7.0 instead of v7.2. In our `local.settings.json` file, we had to set our `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME_VERSION` to point to PowerShell v7.2.

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME_VERSION": "7.2",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "powershell"
  }
}
```

Originally, we had our runtime version set to `~7`. It was hard to both identify and diagnose because technically, the PowerShell application *was* executing. If you're not running this through Azure FunctionApps, I'd say check to make sure you're actually running your script in PowerShell v7.2. Moreover, ensure you're actually using `ExchangeOnlineManagement=3.1.0` when trying to call `Connect-ExchangeOnline`. Microsoft's docs should list PowerShell v7.2 as the minimum required version for this Exchange Online module as this took a good deal of time to diagnose and resolve. However, I doubt they'll ever do this.

Answer (score 1):

I have been encountering the same issue and determined it is incompatibility with some .dll files in the PartnerCenter module in comparison to the newer ExchangeOnlineManagement module.

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll
```

What I have done so far was copy the above .dll files from the ExchangeOnlineManagement module into PartnerCenter and replaced them. I now get a different error, but it's not .dll related! I realize this isn't a full answer, but it should get you farther than you are now, hopefully.